# Xamarin Forms ToolbarItem text (only) is not displaying on Android (only)

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, toolbar

I have a working Xamarin Forms app for Android and [UWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform). (I have not yet attempted iOS.) I have the following *ToolbarItem*:

```xml
<ContentPage Title="Debug" ...  >

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="Question_16x.png" Text="Help" Clicked="OnHelpPressed" Order="Primary" Priority="0"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
...
```

On UWP it works as I would expect:

[image]

But on Android, either the Android simulator or a Samsung phone, I get just a very muddy question mark icon and no text "Help":

[image]

If I remove the icon the text displays.

On both platforms, clicking or tapping the item drives the *Clicked* method as expected. It is the exact same icon in both projects.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android and iOS, you could use the code below to display text and icons:

```xml
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="Question_16x.png" Order="Primary" Priority="0"/>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Help"Clicked="OnHelpPressed" Order="Primary" Priority="0"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Comment: Well Bingo! Why didn't I think of that?

Comment: Would be nice if I could make the icon not quite so "muddy" but this is a 100% improvement!

Comment: FYI, one can play with the order of the two ToolbarItem's, and get either "Help ?" or "? Help" as one prefers.

Answer (score 1):

To have an icon be less "muddy", use a larger icon bitmap.

Here is a question mark, designed to be high-resolution on a high DPI device (It's higher resolution than needed; shrink it down if you want):

[image: High-resolution question mark]

It is derived from [Wikimedia - Icon-round-Question_mark.jpg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Icon-round-Question_mark.jpg).

--- To see more icons, go to [Wikimedia Category:icons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Icons). It’s not the most convenient to browse; it’s easier to google what you want: *Wikimedia icon question mark* ---

Place this file in `YourProjectName.Android\Resources\drawable` folder.
In the project's Solution Explorer pane, right-click that folder, "Add Existing Item", and browse to that file. This sets *Build Action* to *"AndroidResource"*.

If you examine that file in a [paint app](https://www.getpaint.net/), you'll see that there is some transparent area "padding" surrounding the question mark picture.

This is per [Material Design icons in app bar / Specs - Mobile](https://material.io/components/app-bars-top#specs). To adjust, in a paint app, use "Image / Canvas Size" to change the amount of padding.

It was tested in [xamarin-forms-samples/UserInterface/ToolbarItemDemos](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/UserInterface/ToolbarItemDemos).

Comment: Marvelous. I was going to post a screen shot here but I guess *comments* can't have images. Interesting -- Android reverses the black to white so that it shows on the dark blue background.

Comment: And thanks. I tried to mark this as an answer but you can only have one answer I guess, and @Adrain Zhu -MSFT answered my original question. I marked this a helpful, because it really was. Heck, I was unaware of the Wikimedia icon collection -- GREAT resource.

Comment: @Charles - glad I could help :)